# Laravel merge views to compact

Tags: laravel

I'm want merge some views, because I got different types of notification and I got the HTML and each view... How I can make it?

```
function index(){
    $notifications = Notify::where('notifiable_id', auth()->user()->id)->take(5)->get();

    foreach($notifications as $notification):
        if($notification->type == 'App\Notifications\NotifyLinkOwnerComment'):

            $data = json_decode($notification->data, true);
            //comment
            //view('site.list.header.notifications.commentlink', compact('notification', 'data'));

       elseif($notification->type == 'App\Notifications\NotifyCommentOwnerReply'):
            //reply
            //view('site.list.header.notifications.commentreply', compact('notification', 'data'));
        endif;
    endforeach;

    //views in compact = all views merged
    return view("site.balloons.header.notifications", compact('notifications', 'views'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `render` method on the `view` to get it as a `string` and then save it to a variable for later use.

```
$views = '';
foreach($notifications as $notification):
    if($notification->type == 'App\Notifications\NotifyLinkOwnerComment'):

        $data = json_decode($notification->data, true);
        //comment
        $views .= view('site.list.header.notifications.commentlink', compact('notification', 'data'))->render();

   elseif($notification->type == 'App\Notifications\NotifyCommentOwnerReply'):
        //reply
        $views .= view('site.list.header.notifications.commentreply', compact('notification', 'data'))->render();
    endif;
endforeach;
```